# Android scroll up

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have two buttons Button 1, Button 2 placed horizontally like tabs. On Click of these button I am adding Linear Layout in Scroll View.

Now suppose I am clicking Button 1 and scroll down and immediately switch or click to Button 2 that scroll applies on newly added layout. I want every time on click of button content should scroll to top.

I have tried `scrollview.scrollT0(0,0)` and `scrollview.scrollTo(0,scrollview.getTop())` but none of them is working.

Comment: please add your code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ran into these types of issues before.

I suggest trying the following:

```
scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollview.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```

The reason this works is forces the action in the Main Thread which is where all UI Activity happens (safely, of course).

Comment: @David- I am not using List View. just adding linear layout in scroll view.

Comment: @David- Thank you.. Working nicely... Appreciate your valuable help... :)

Comment: No problem! I've spent far too long on that issue :). Don't forget to accept and upvote :)

Comment: @David- Yes... fantastic code .. but cant vote up as it need 15 + reputation.

Comment: @sog, if you can't upvote, you can mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this . Just it is sample

```
private void scrollMyListViewToBottom() {
        your_list.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (!running) {

             // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
                your_list.setSelection(your_list.getCount() - 1);
                running = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Note :
Before call this method just change `Boolean running = false;`